# direction: rtl with text-align: center doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have a strange issue i don't understand. this is my CSS

```
    .tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
    background: #222222; 
  background: #fff;
    opacity: .9;
    color: #eeeeee; 
  color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 12px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.tooltip .title {
  text-align: center;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

and this is my html:

```
<span class="tooltip">
<span class="title">טקסט בעברית </span>
</span>
```

but for some reason my text is directed rtl but is aligned to the left from all places!
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: "is centered to the left from all places" - what does that mean? The center is the center, i.e. not left or right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I see what you mean - your text in `<span class="title">` isn't center-aligned: http://jsfiddle.net/24e94/1/

This is because `<span>`s are displayed as inline elements by default (i.e. they're only as wide as their contents).

You need to either set that `<span>` to `display:block`, or do the same to its parent and move `text-align:center` to the parent.

- http://jsfiddle.net/24e94/

Answer (score 3):

use `display:block`

```
.tooltip .title {
   display:block;
   text-align: center;
   direction: rtl;
}
```